# API not being served on IIS, but it is with Kestrel

Tags: asp.net-core, iis-8

I am publishing an app to my self hosted iis server.

I then run the app with dotnet myapp.dll and the app runs correctly.

However, when I turn on IIS and try to access the site, all static files show properly, but the API calls return 404 not found.

This is the request. Note that it is an options call. Do I need to configure something in the API to handle those? (I just tried on a different computer, and it showed it as a GET, not OPTIONS, but same 404 error.

```
OPTIONS /api/Entity/list-active HTTP/1.1
Host: greggum.com
Connection: keep-alive
Pragma: no-cache
Cache-Control: no-cache
Access-Control-Request-Method: GET
Origin: http://96.254.154.55
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/52.0.2743.116 Safari/537.36
Access-Control-Request-Headers: content-type
Accept: */*
Referer: http://96.254.154.55/
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, sdch
Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.8
```

Comment: there are many things that could not be correct. Are you sure in the startup.cs you have app.UseMVC() available?

Comment: Yes, I do have that set.

Comment: and for the routes of the api how are they set? at controller and individual actions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you followed the [Publishing to IIS](https://docs.asp.net/en/latest/publishing/iis.html) docs?

Particularly the [.NET Core Windows Server Hosting bundle](https://docs.asp.net/en/latest/publishing/iis.html#install-the-net-core-windows-server-hosting-bundle) that has to be installed.

Also, note that unlike a standard ASP.NET application, you'll be running a [Unmanaged Application Pool](https://docs.asp.net/en/latest/publishing/iis.html#configure-the-website-in-iis).

Comment: Yes, I have read that,  I have installed that bundle, and I have set the Working Process to No Managed Code.

Comment: Have you inspected the application log files to see if the request reached your app? Is there anything on event log? https://docs.asp.net/en/latest/publishing/iis.html#common-errors has details on troubleshooting this.

Comment: No, I have not. Let me check.

Comment: Ok, found issue.  Says `Login failed for user 'IIS APPPOOL\app.rihisi.com'. ` However, I am supplying a sql server username/password, so this doesn't make sense.

Comment: It was using integrated authentication, but I changed it and restarted IIS. So it ought to be working now.